# sizeof char array is off by one

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I want to use the sizeof function to get the size of a char array. The size that I get is one too much. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char text[] = "hey";
const int n = sizeof(text);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%i\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs 4, instead of the expected 3. I reproduced this behaviour on various online c++ compilers, so I think it is intended (oddly enough, I can't find anything about on the internet). Most sources that I can find online say that it should be 3 * sizeof(char) (which is 3 on most normal systems).

If I understand everything correctly, there is an extra byte that is used for the array representation in some way. Why does this happen?

Comment: it's a string. you forgot the null terminator. `hey\0`

Comment: see for example: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Comment: Time to read your book again.

Comment: @MarcB I forgot nothing. When I add a null terminator, it returns 5.

Comment: `"hey\0"` adds a *second* null terminator; it's equivalent to `{'h', 'e', 'y', '\0', '\0'}`, just as `"hey"` is equivalent to `{'h', 'e', 'y', '\0'}`. (Equivalent in this context; more generally, string literals can be used in contexts that don't allow initializers.)

Comment: The compiler adds a hidden null character behind your back.

Comment: There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals are implicitly `NUL` terminated, so `"hey"` is actually four characters in size; the three letters you see, plus a `\0` (aka `NUL`).

When you initialize an array without specifying a size, it's sizing it to match the initializer, and the initializer is that four byte quantity including the `NUL`. `char text[] = "hey";` is equivalent to saying `char text[] = {'h', 'e', 'y', '\0'};`. If it didn't work like this, attempting to work with the contents of the array as a C-style string would run past the buffer into neighboring memory until it found a `NUL` terminator by coincidence.

Comment: Technically, it is not correct. Nothing is 'is making room'. It's just that string literals are implicitly null-terminated. The string literal initialization uses as many characters as there are in the literal.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the null terminator is actually stored in memory?

Comment: @MonKeePoo: Yes, it is (unless the compiler is able to optimize it away somehow, but that typically doesn't happen).

Comment: Got it, thanks. I always thought this was the programmers job. Normally, I always terminate string with \0.

Comment: Yes, it is. It has to be or attempts to work with string literals as if they were C-style strings would all lead to buffer read overruns. Every C string related function requires that space exist for, and be filled with a `NUL` terminator. If you're not trying to use real strings, just initializing the array to those values (and you'll never `printf` the array without an explicit size, `strlen` it, etc.), then you can use explicit value by value initialization (`{'h', 'e', 'y'}`). You may also be able to explicitly size the array to 3; not sure if the C standard officially supports that.

Comment: I would advocate to learn how to use a debugger (and get comfortable using it) early in the learning process, when faced with problems like these it allows you to pause the program during execution and look at the contents of the memory.